# TYPO3 fluid Paginate Widget only remembers form post once (8.7.10)

Tags: forms, post, typo3

I have a search form with the ability to filter categories etc using a POST form submission. 
The results of the search are paginated using the Fluid Paginate widget.

After performing a search , when I click one of the paginated buttons (page 2 for example), the submitted POST data from my filtered search is retained. But when I click a paginated button a second time, the filtered data is lost, and only the page number data is retained.

My pagination code looks like so:

```
<f:widget.paginate objects="{eventList}" as="paginatedEventList" configuration="{itemsPerPage: 15, addQueryStringMethod: 'POST'}">
```

My form filter search form begins so:

```
<f:form method="POST" action="list" id="eventsearch" name="eventsearch" class="eventsearchform">
```

Does anybody have any idea why this might be happening?

Answer (score 0):

The paginate widget does not use POST to submit the data when you click the link, but adds the POST data to the query string of the link. So after you click the link, the data is send through GET, not POST. Because you set `addQueryStringMethod` to `POST` it won't add the GET data to the query string, so the links won't have the data.

Comment: Thanks. I tried via GET to but I had the same issue. In the end I made my own pagination widget.